# route packets for 2 eth's

Tags: ethernet, nat, routing

I have 2 ethernet cards on my 1st computer
eth0 10.1.1.254/24
eth1 10.2.1.254/24

eth0 is connected to 2nd computers eth0 using crossover cabe
which is 
10.1.1.1

I can ping computer 1 eth0 from computer 2
But I cant ping computer 1 eth1 from computer 2

how do I route packets to eth1 of computer 1
via eth0 of same computer

I am trying out setting up NAT on my local computers, I need this for working out different types of NAT

Comment: Sounds like your kernel is patched for the ARP flux problem, but you want to induce ARP flux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at some guides for how to set up iptables, as it will basically allow you to route packets between interfaces according to rules you set up.  iptables is much more than just a firewall interface and you can pretty much give it a massive list of rules to route data through networks.

That tiny router that almost everyone uses to connect to the internet with?  That thing is running Linux with iptables fully set up.

Amongst others, look at this [howtoforge guide](http://www.howtoforge.com/nat_iptables) and  this epic guide at [pettingers](http://www.pettingers.org/code/firewall.html)

The main one I can find is this one which claims to be [A basic firewall configuration suitable for a gateway/nat](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/A_basic_firewall_configuration_suitable_for_a_gateway/nat) and supports eth0 for the external interface and eth1 for the internal interface.

Ubuntu has an [IpTables Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo) and as an example has a program called [UFW (Uncomplicated FireWall)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) that may be able to configure iptables for you, it also has a gui frontend called [gufw](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Gufw) which may be of use.